# Django db rollback specific commits

Tags: django, database, postgresql, rollback

I have a django model called `User`
I have a method that takes a list of different user updates like this `[user1_payload, user2_payload, user3_payload,...,user100_payload]`
Some updates can fail in the database.
There is another third party api which takes a list of user updates and perform the update action on their end.
I would like to take only the successful updates in the database and call the third party api. Keep in mind that the third party api can also have some failed update operations and will return a response like this:

```
{
    "successful_users": [1, 3, 5,...],
    "failed_users": [2, 4,...]
}
```

In case of the failed users in the third party api, i want to rollback those updates in my db.
How can I achieve this using minimum number of db transactions and minimum number of api calls using django?